# MySQL CREATE table with > 4000 fields (with large sized colums)

Tags: mysql-5.7

I wish to `CREATE` a table with 4000+ columns but an error happens.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:/OECD-Bot/src/csvTomysql.py", line 55, in <module>
    cursor.execute(creatQueryString)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 551, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 490, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 395, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `csv_db`.`ear_mei` (errno: 185 "Too many columns")
```

Answer (score 1):

[4096](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html) is the limit.

Innodb has a [1017](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-limits.html) limit.

Reconsider your design.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html#column-count-limits) can be helpful! In your case, I think you need to read the entire page carefully - but of particular note are the following:

Firstly:

> `MySQL has hard limit of 4096 columns per table, but the effective
>   maximum may be less for a given table. The exact column limit depends
>   on several factors:`

Some of these are:

> `The maximum row size for a table constrains the number (and possibly
>   size) of columns because the total length of all columns cannot exceed
>   this size. See Row Size Limits.`

and

> `Storage requirements for some data types depend on factors such as
>   storage engine, storage format, and character set`

If you're using Chinese character sets, this might reduce the number of characters that you can use per row - multi-byte character sets - up to [4 bytes per character](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-cjk.html).

Of particular note is this:

> `For example, InnoDB has a limit of 1017 columns per table.`

Are you using InnoDB? You can [check](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-check-availability.html)! InnoDB is the default for MySQL 5.7 - [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-introduction.html) to the rescue again!

> `In MySQL 5.7, InnoDB is the default MySQL storage engine.`

Also, of interest to you (large size columns):

`The internal representation of a MySQL table has a maximum row size limit of 65,535 bytes, even if the storage engine is capable of supporting larger rows. BLOB and TEXT columns only contribute 9 to 12 bytes toward the row size limit because their contents are stored separately from the rest of the row.`

So, if your columns are `BLOB` or `TEXT` fields, you will have a minimum of 9 bytes per field, so "large" (what is **your** definition of "large"?) fields may or may not be a problem depending on their datatypes!

As I said, read the entire page for a complete guide to this area. Also, I would **seriously** consider redesigning my database if you have a requirement for this many fields in one table! Is this SQL `CREATE` statement automatically generated by a framework of some sort? You might have to roll up your sleeves and get down to the core of that framework? If you have any further issues, don't hesitate to get back to us.

p.s. welcome to the forum!